# Diferença na prática de operadores aritmético e de atribuição

Tags: java, operadores

```
package entities;
public class Product {
      public String name;
      public double price;
      public int quantity;

      public double totalValueInStock() {
          return price * quantity;
      }
      public void addProducts(int quantity) {
          this.quantity += quantity;
      }
      public void removeProducts(int quantity) {
          this.quantity -= quantity;
      }
      public String toString() {
          return name
                + ", $ "
                + String.format("%.2f", price)
                + ", "
                + quantity
                + " units, Total: $ "
                + String.format("%.2f", totalValueInStock());
      }
}`
```

Eu pensei ter entendido a diferença entre esses tópicos básicos mas não consegui explicar qual a real diferença entre um e outro...

Observem ali: `this.quantity += quantity;`, foi usado o operador de atribuição += que diz que "this.quantity RECEBE this.quantity + quantity".

Porém não consigo ver a diferença entre ele e o operador aritmético +, ambos fariam a mesma operação, não? Não consegui entender esse "RECEBE".

Qual seria a real diferença entre um e outro de forma clara, sem dizer que exemplo: `a += 2` significa "a RECEBE a + 2".

Isso eu entendi, se "a" valer 10 o resultado de a += 2 é 12 porém, a + 2 também resulta em 12. Me entenderam?

Por que usar um e não outro?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

O nome correto do que está usando é operador composto. Porque ele é composto por uma aritmética mais uma atribuição do resultado.

Dependendo da implementação da linguagem o seu uso pode habilitar alguma otimização e consequente uso de uma instrução mais eficiente e por isso ter performance melhor (`iadd` X `iinc`).

Quando mistura-se tipos numéricos essa forma infere o tipo correto, na aritmética separada pode dar erro de tipagem.

Além disto dá uma semântica mais clara para quem sabe programar que está alterando o estado com aquela operação aritmética, sem falar que fica mais curto, e o curto tende ser mais legível.

Do ponto de vista conceitual elas fazem a mesma coisa e o operador composto pode ser lido como uma contração da expressão que faz a aritmética e depois a atribuição.

Mas em termos de como executa, ao contrário do que foi dito em outra resposta, não é apenas gosto, ainda que dê o mesmo resultado.

Answer (score 3):

É exatamente igual, tanto se pode usar um como o outro, **são apenas preferencias**! 
Há quem diga que também toca um bocado na compreensão de código (a = a+2 ser mais facil de compreender que a+=2) mas não se preocupe muito com isso.

Answer (score 2):

Não há diferença conceitual entre ambas. Nos dois casos, você está definindo que `a` passa a valer o valor atual de `a` mais 2, o que você corretamente afirmou ser 12.

O termo "receber" é comum na programação e não tem a ver necessariamente com esse operador composto `+=`, mas sim com qualquer operação na qual você atribui um valor a uma variável. Quando diz "`a` recebe `a + 2`", é apenas uma maneira de dizer que este valor está sendo "atribuído", "definido", "alocado" na variável `a`.

`String nome = "José"` pode ser lido como "a variável `nome` recebe o valor" José".